# Dynamic Arrays in If Statements Conditions

Tags: dynamic-arrays, freepascal

I am currently working on a Free Pascal program. As part of the coding, I need to access arrays in the If Statements Conditions. For example, I was using a code similar to this:

If (SumArray[s]) > 0 And (AverageArray[a]) < 10 then...

This syntax is not working. I need the correct Free Pascal syntax to use the arrays in the conditions for the If Statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
If (SumArray[s] > 0)  And (AverageArray[a] < 10) then
```

The reason that parens are needed is that the `and` operator has higher precedence than comparison operators.

If you look at your code you will see that the expressions inside your parens have no operators and so your parens serve no purpose.

Comment: Thank you but I noticed that when I am using the For loop to access the arrays, it is printing extra lines. Take a look at this:                                    for s:=Low(SumArray) to High(SumArray) do
       for a:=Low (AverageArray) to High(AverageArray) do

Comment: I think I answered the question you asked, right? We can't be expected to decipher random extracts of code in follow up comments.

Comment: These are my codes: Thank you but I noticed that when I am using the For loop to access the arrays, it is printing extra lines. Take a look at this: for s:=Low(SumArray) to High(SumArray) do
       for a:=Low (AverageArray) to High(AverageArray) do Total:= s * 2.25                                                                                                              for s:=Low(SumArray) to High(SumArray) do
       for a:=Low (AverageArray) to High(AverageArray) do                          writeln('The figures are: ', SumArray[s], AverageArray[a]);

Comment: @ITPrincess: that would be a new question. Do not put new questions in comments. They are not only hard to read, they are the wrong place for such questions. Just ask a new question. David answered your question, so please accept the answer (click the checkmark beside it).

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here. :)